# MySQL Join Unknown Number of Tables

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database containing a primary table and some unknown number of secondary tables. The primary table has two columns: ID (which is the primary key) and name. Secondary tables can have any number of columns, but are guaranteed to have the ID column as their primary key. Furthermore, the ID column of secondary tables is guaranteed to reference the ID column of the primary table as a foreign key. Additionally, it can be assumed that every table in the database has every ID.

I am currently using Python to construct and send queries to the MySQL database. What I would like to be able to do is to construct a query that will join all the tables in the database together by their ID columns. I understand that I can use `SHOW TABLES;` to return all the tables in the database, but I can't figure out how to generate a MySQL query for an unknown number of joins from there.

Example: I have three tables: A, B, and C. A is the primary table and thus has columns ID and name. B has columns ID, foo, and bar. C has columns ID and baz. I need to construct a join such that I get a table that has columns ID, name, foo, bar, and baz.

Edit: To give more detail, my python program is running some unknown number of modules, each of which stores information the object in its own table in the database that fits the constraints for secondary tables I mentioned previously. I could store everything in one much wider table (thus avoiding the joins entirely), but that would require me to add columns as more modules get added, which feels weird to me. I'm hardly an SQL expert though, so that might be the way to go. Even if that is what I end up doing, I'm still curious about how one might go about doing this.

Comment: Why can't you just define the queries you really need at design time? That is how you do it normally. Static queries.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tool for the job here?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I should be using a relational database for this problem, yes. The way I'm going about it could be entirely wrong though.

Comment: You should use an ORM solution in which you can do the joins programmatically. You would probably need some meta tables as well to describe the table structures or use information_schema tables to retrieve tables, columns, and foreign keys for joins.

Comment: @Shadow That looks like what I was looking for, thanks!